# Overriding or removing style to React component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

Currently struggling with React.
I have a component `Model.Dialog` which is a dependency that I can not modify it directly.

The `Modal.Dialog` CSS is:

```
.Modal {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex
}
```

The render method that calls the component is:

```
render() {

    return (
        <Modal.Dialog
            id="PicModal"
            isOpen={this.props.isOpen}
            onClose={this._handleClose}
            modifier={'large'}
            ariaHideApp={false}
        >
            <Modal.Body className={Styles.PicModal}>
                <Button
                    className={Styles.closeBtn}
                    modifier="styleless"
                    onClick={this._handleClose}
                    dataTest="pic-close"
                >
                    <IconCross height="24" />
                </Button>
                <div id="picContainer" data-test="pic-container" />
            </Modal.Body>
        </Modal.Dialog>
    );
}
```

I need to change the `overflow: auto` to `overflow: revert`, and I've tried several things such as:

- Adding `<Modal.Dialog style={{overflow:"revert"}} ...  </Modal.Dialog>`
- Creating a custom CSS with all the properties, changing the `overflow` to `revert` and inserting 
  `<Modal.Dialog className=CSSTEST ... </Modal.Dialog>`
- Adding a IdSelector `#PicModal { overflow: revert; }`

However none of this worked... Any Suggestions?

EDIT: Removing the `overflow` property would work as well. It is possible?

Comment: can I ask what Modal library you're using, so I can have a look at

Comment: Something currently has a higher specificity than the CSS selectors you have tried. Check your dev tools to see what selector is currently being matched so we can see if there is a way to make a more specific one.

Comment: did you try ```<Modal.Dialog style={{ overflow: "revert !important" }} ...  </Modal.Dialog> ```

Comment: @DucHong , Sorry but is not acessible, it is a custom made library in the company.

Comment: I don't think `revert` is a valid value for `overflow`, at least I cannot find it in the [DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: @Titus It is, I changed it directly in the browser and does the expected result.

Comment: Oh, it seems to be a value similar to `unset`.

Comment: I think it is the issue of the DOM object hierarchy. You may not access the dom object using the above way.

Comment: @AfiaUdofia It does not work as well.

Comment: can you send me the live URL so that I can inspect the DOM tree?

Comment: hmm.. then I think you should screenshot the computed value of `<Moda.Dialog />` so we might see what's holding the `overflow` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. After struggling with the trial and error method, the solution to my problem was a different approach for CSS selector.

This did the trick:

```
div[id="PicModal"] {
    overflow: revert;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess one potential way is to use css selector. You can inspect the dom tree and learn the exact path.
For example

```css
#PicModal > div > p:nth-child(2) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```